# Flexbox - How to create a border around and between differently sized items

Tags: html, css, flexbox, border-spacing

I'm trying to make a Flexbox that looks like this:
[Flexbox layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ivM1.png), where there's a border around the entire Flexbox, as well as between the two items.

My issue is that I can either get a border around the entire Flexbox, but not between the items, or I can add a border between the items but it doesn't stretch the entire length of the Flexbox.

I've played around with align-content, align-items, justify-content, margins, padding...I just can't figure out how to have 2 items that are centered vertically and horizontally, with a border that stretches the length of the box.

Thanks so much in advance!

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    height: 300px;
    border: solid red 2px;
    align-items: center;
    
}

.content {
    border: solid grey 2px;
    flex-basis: 50%;
    padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="content">
            <img href="#fillThisInLater" alt="circle" titel="Circle">
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis rerum iste ratione cum sit illo est tenetur fugit sapiente eum enim maiores laborum voluptatem amet, alias vero, ut velit eos!
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your flex container has a defined `height`, the border issue will be solved if you add `height: 100%;` and `box-sizing: border-box;` to the flex-items.

EDIT: To center the contents inside the flex-items, make them also flex-containers with settings as shown below:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid red 2px;
}

.content {
  border: solid grey 2px;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="content">
    <img href="#fillThisInLater" alt="circle" titel="Circle">
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis rerum iste ratione cum sit illo est tenetur fugit sapiente eum enim maiores laborum voluptatem amet, alias vero, ut velit eos!
  </div>
</div>
```

If you only want a "middle line"  and no separate outside borders for the flex items, just only apply a `border-right` to the first flex-item:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid red 2px;
}

.content {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;  
}
.content:first-child {
  border-right: solid grey 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="content">
    <img href="#fillThisInLater" alt="circle" titel="Circle">
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis rerum iste ratione cum sit illo est tenetur fugit sapiente eum enim maiores laborum voluptatem amet, alias vero, ut velit eos!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @EmielZuurbier As you can see in my snippets, the contents *are* centered. But probably you wrote your comment while I was editing my answer - I had overseen the wish for centering before and concentrated on the border issue.

Comment: @Johannes - adding the display:flex to the child elements did the trick for me! I don't understand why that was necessary, though. I guess they don't inherit the display:flex from the parent?  Is there documentation I could read that explains exactly why this was necessary?

Comment: No, `display: flex` isn't inherited

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Oh, that `align-items: center` was in the question code and I simply didn't/forgot to remove it. As you say, it doesn't do anything in this case. I removed it now.

Answer (score 0):

Fit the child elements to entire height

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  /* border: solid red 2px; */
  /* align-items: center; */
}

.content {
  border: solid grey 2px;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  /* padding: 30px; */
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <img href="#fillThisInLater" alt="circle" titel="Circle" />
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis rerum
    iste ratione cum sit illo est tenetur fugit sapiente eum enim maiores
    laborum voluptatem amet, alias vero, ut velit eos!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @EmielZuurbier That was not part of my answer, that was from the question only. Anyhow, removed that one

Answer (score 0):

To remove the double border in the middle, remove the 'left' side from the last-child:

```css
.container > div:last-child {
  border-left: unset;
}
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    height: 300px;
    border: solid red 2px;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    border: solid grey 2px;
    flex-basis: 50%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}

.container > div:last-child {
  border-left: unset;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="content">
            <img href="#fillThisInLater" alt="circle" titel="Circle">
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis rerum iste ratione cum sit illo est tenetur fugit sapiente eum enim maiores laborum voluptatem amet, alias vero, ut velit eos!
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate a border-like line by using the [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap) property in combination with a background color. With it you can create space between the flex-items and let the background color of the container bleed through.

This method will make having a dynamic number of rows and columns a lot easier to handle compared using the `border` property.

```css
.container {
  --border-width: 2px;
  display: flex;
  gap: var(--border-width);
  height: 300px;
  border: solid grey var(--border-width);
  align-content: center;
  background: grey;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  background: white;
}

.inner-content {
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="inner-content">
        <img href="#fillThisInLater" alt="circle" titel="Circle">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
      <div class="inner-content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Facilis rerum iste ratione cum sit illo est tenetur fugit sapiente eum enim maiores laborum voluptatem amet, alias vero, ut velit eos!
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: This is a fascinating alternative. Is this any more or less expensive than using the `border` property? I understand the benefits of using it, I'm just wondering if there's a reason not to always use this.

Comment: I don't believe that it would make any difference performance-wise. The `gap` property used to be available for `grid` only. Flexbox Gap was only fully supported since last year, so it's relatively new. And it totally depends on what you're building. In your case it makes sense as you have a line that splits both children up, and it still gives you the option to add another border around each `.content` div if you'd want. Many ways to Rome..